# The easiest way of getting data from different site

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to grab static data from different website (URL and elements name provided), what's the easiest way?

**www.address/articles/grab-this**

```
<html>
   (...)
   <article id="#article-121">
     <h1>Header</h1>
     <p>Contents</p>
    </article>
   (...)
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
/* Grab "#article-121" from www.address/articles/grab-this */

   <article id="#article-121">
         <h1>Header</h1>
         <p>Contents</p>
   </article>

/* Close the connection */
```

Comment: duplicated search parse html php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

```
$contents = file_get_contents(url_goes_here);
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but I guess getting exact element based on ID is much more harder?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Once you have the `$contents` you should be able to manipulate/parse it